# SAS Data integration studio

Tags: sas, integration, where-clause, summary

Long time reader first-time questioner.

Using SAS Data Integration studio, when you create a summary transformation in the table options advanced tab you can add a where statement to your code automatically. Unfortunately, it adds some code that makes this resolve incorrectly. Putting the following in the where text box:

```
TESTFIELD = "TESTVALUE"
```

creates

```
%let _INPUT_options = %nrquote(WHERE = %(TESTFIELD = %"TESTVALUE%"%));
```

In the code, used

```
proc tabulate data = &_INPUT (&_INPUT_options)
```

But resolves to

```
WHERE = (TESTFIELD = "TESTVALUE")

                 _
                 22
```

> ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause. ERROR 22-322: Syntax
>   error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a
>   numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
>                 a missing value, (, *, +, -, :, INPUT, NOT, PUT, ^, ~.

My question is this: Is there a way to add a function to the where statement box that would allow this quotation mark to be properly added here?

Note that all functions get the preceding % when added to the where statement automatically and I have no control over that. This seems like something that should be relatively easy to fix but I haven't found a simple way yet.

Comment: Did you generate the PROC TABULATE code? Or was that also generated by the tool? That is can you add in %UNQUOTE() to remove the macro quoting that was added in the %LET statement?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is automatically generated. The only portion I can make adjustments to is the text box for the where statement. Everything else is generated from that.

Comment: In that case raise a support ticket with SAS.  Perhaps there is some option somewhere to prevent DIS from adding the macro quoting.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yeah, if DIS is doing *all* of this then it's a DIS issue.  If you have control over the code at all, you can use my answer, but if you have zero then you can't.

Comment: Yeah I can change it to user code, but using the tabulate function it seems like a huge limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` are simply escaping the `"` and `()` characters; they're perfectly harmless, really.  The bigger problem is the `%NRQUOTE` "quotes" (which are nonprinting characters that tell SAS this is macro-quoted); they mess up the `WHERE` processing.

Use [`%UNQUOTE( ... )`](http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmmvacdc&cdcVersion=9.4&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1k3cotqhvgwk0n105gyfe1cqg9m.htm&locale=en) to remove these.

Example:

```
data have;
  testfield="TESTVALUE";
  output;
  testfield="AMBASDF";
  output;
run;

%let _INPUT_options = %nrquote(WHERE = %(TESTFIELD = %"TESTVALUE%"%));
%put &=_input_options;

data want;
  set have(%unquote(&_INPUT_options.));
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately the %NRQUOTE is system generated when the where text box is filled and cannot be edited outside of that text box. Putting an %UNQOUTE in the where statement moves the error to the start of the %UNQOUTE, and seems to not resolve %UNQOUTE

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. Long story short, I ended up creating a SAS Troubleshooting ticket. The analyst told me that they have now documented the  issue, which should now be resolved in a future iteration of DI.

The temporary solution was to create a new transformation, with a slight alteration, adding an UNQOUTE (as mentioned above by Joe) to the source code before the input options:

proc tabulate data = &_INPUT **(%unquote**(&_INPUT_options)) %unquote(&procOptions);

For those interested you will need to create the transformation in a public subfolder of your project so others can use it. Not what I was hoping for, but a workable solution while waiting for the version update.